# How to us python scripting to create, connect and change an image texture node

Tags: python, texturing, scripting, shader-nodes

Im curious of how to automate creation of shader nodes and and end up with an image texture connected to the color-input of a Principled BSDF.

This would have been easy if copy-pasting from info-console was possible as it is with creating and smoothing a mesh for instance, but for some reason doesnt work here.
(I have made sure to enable nodes)

Obviously I'm fairly new to scripting in Blender.

Any response is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Thank you!
Probably but I'm getting an error at the line: 
nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes

Comment: From console: 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'node_tree'

Comment: No problem. Create a material in the first place and enable 'use nodes', then run the script (... and set the path to your texture).

Comment: Fantastic, thanks. That got us past that, but seems to be one last problem with the path

From console: 
RuntimeError: Error: Cannot read 'C:    estImg\ironman_whammmm.jpg': Invalid argument

Comment: Heres the line: 
node_tex.image = bpy.data.images.load("C:\testImg\ironman_whammmm.jpg")

Comment: Try: `C:\\testImg\\ironman_whammmm.jpg`

Comment: You are a hero. It worked.